# iPhone - Cannot run apps from XCode on iOS 5.0.1 device, since iOS update from 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I have just updated my iPhone to iOS 5.0.1 and XCode doesn't recognize it anymore as a valid device to run applications.

I have gone to the organizer, reset the device as a development device, updated my components and library... but still nothing. The device doesn't appear in the available destinations into the main window popup...

How can I do to test again on the device ?

Comment: are you using the current build of XCode 4.2? We have not had this issue at all with any 5.0.1 devices.

Comment: Did you have any issues getting it to collect the debugging symbols? Mine starts but never gets beyond "Copying file (1 of 7)"

Comment: @drewish : No, mine did not even recognize the phone

Comment: I downloaded the ipsw file and added that to XCode and it was able to download the debugging symbols. It seems like OTA updates will cause some issues with that going forward.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Disconnect your iPhone.
2. Quit iTunes & XCode.
3. Turn off and restart your iPhone.
4. Connect your iPhone, wait for itunes to finish syncing (if you have it set to launch automatically).
5. Close iTunes, then open XCode.
6. Go to organizer and see if it recognizes the iPhone for development or will let you re-enable use for development.
7. If all that fails, reset your iPhone (gasp!) then do all this again.  =(

Comment: This fixed a problem I was having when I changed the bundle identifier, where it would build and deploy to the device, but throw an error that it was unable to run the executable.

Answer (score 5):

Select your device in Xcode's organizer, and the click "Add to Portal". Xcode will communicate with the mothership, decide your device is OK after all, and it will then once again become available for testing.

Comment: I tried that but it keeps getting stuck trying to collect the debugging symbols. I'm wondering if it's because I got the update OTA rather than via iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

Also if your deployment target is higher than the OS version of the device, it will not show up as a valid device.

Answer (score 2):

it worked for me like this:

- select the main project on the left window of Xcode
- select the "summary" tab on the central window.
- change "deployment target" to 5.0
- click "validate settings"
- that's it. Now my device is on the list!
- select the device and click Run

Xcode 4.3.2, Lion 10.7.3, iPhone4 iOS 5.0.1, (using Jailcoder)