# Xcode doesn't recognize IPad after iPad reset

Tags: xcode, ipad

I have been building and running an app on an iPhone and an iPad, both with OS 5.1, on Xcode 4.2.

but today a did a reset on the iPad (by pressing and holding home+lock buttons).
Since then, xcode doesn't recognize the iPad. Organizer says that version of iOS installed on iPad doesn't match with the supported versions of xcode.

if i right click on my iPad (in organizer) and click on "add to provisionling profile", i receive a popup saying request timed out.

Comment: Did the iTunes recognize the device? You can try a synchronization from the iTunes.

Comment: I didn't try anything with iTunes. Can you tell me what exactly to do in 'synchronization'. I am new to mac.

Edit: iTunes recognizes the device and shows the details of the device

Comment: Yes. If you connect the iPad to your Mac, and open the iTunes, the iPad will appear in the left list, under the "Devices". Here you should choose the "Apps" and press the "Synchronize" button. I hope I'm right, I having no iPad right now near me to try this :)

Comment: if i do that, it says that it will remove all devices in the list and install those apps which i select to sync with. I don't get how working with apps is the solution to this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked for some solutions on the net, please check the following problems + answers, maybe one of them is your solution too :)
[First link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100820/iphone-cannot-run-apps-from-xcode-on-ios-5-0-1-device-since-ios-update-from-5), [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608854/xcode-and-ios5-1-on-iphone-wont-work), [third link](https://superuser.com/questions/244665/iphone-not-detected-by-mac) (I know, that you have XCode 4.2, but maybe the methodology will be the same). and the [last one](http://modmyi.com/forums/iphone-ipod-touch-sdk-development-discussion/622311-how-make-xcode-see-my-iphone-again.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after restoring ipad 1.
my fix : 
going to xcode organizer,
make sure the ipad device is disconnected,
delete my ipad in the left column (organizer)
connect my ipad, press "use for development" (and maybe login to itunes connect..)